# NetbeansIDE running issues

Tags: netbeans

I made a project on NETBEANS but when i am running my project then this error is coming on 
 Have a look on error
Target "run" does not exist in the project "project_name". 
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Can you add some more details? for example what kind of project are you trying to create?

Comment: it's a web application using jsps and servlets..

Comment: I think that your project properties are messed up... Have you created a simple web application or have you used maven/ant?

Comment: Yaa i have tried with making a simple web application also but facing the same problem.